# How to create own key on soft Keyboard

Tags: java, android, keyboard

In xml file i do next:

```
   <Row>
        <Key android:codes="FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION" android:keyLabel="Start"  />
    </Row>
```

In class Keyboard  in the method onKeyDown i create next construction

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
switch (keyCode) {
case KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION: {

            return true;
}
...
```

but is dont work. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add some action in keypad in android, use

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

There are so many likr Go, Done, Search and many... and perform action by using EditorActionListener

Comment: EditorActionViewer - Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when an action is performed on the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29). Not all key events trigger onKeyDown(). What you should do is implement [OnKeyboardActionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener.html) and use any of the callbacks there that might suit you (either onKey() or onRelease() would work for you I think).